# Do AutoMapper IQueryable extensions still work with EF 6.1?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I keep getting Exceptions when trying to resolve entities with AutoMapper into viewmodels and I can't figure out why.

The following code

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Article, ArticleViewModel>()
   .ForMember(a => a.CreatedDate, a => a.ResolveUsing<DateResolver>())
   .ForMember(a => a.Content, a => a.ResolveUsing<ContentResolver>().ConstructedBy(() =>
      new ContentResolver(articleParserFactory)));

var test = this.context.Articles
         .Project()
         .To<ArticleViewModel>()
         .ToArray();
```

always leads to an exception with message "Can't resolve this to Queryable Expression". How can I remedy that?

EDIT: This doesn't appear to be a problem with .Project().To(), if I remove the ValueResolvers in the above code AutoMapper does its thing. The weird thing is, if I stick to just DateResolver, AutoMapper never enters the ResolveCore method but instead throws that same exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ValueResolvers aren't supported with the Queryable Extensions in AutoMapper:

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions#supported-mapping-options

You can use MapFrom or custom type conversion instead. Which ones to do will depend on what your resolvers do, but keep in mind you can only do what your LINQ provider will be able to handle.

Many times I try not to have AutoMapper handle just formatting concerns, if that's what your resolvers are doing. I would rather that be handled at the View/Serializer layer, the extension points are much deeper there.